# (MySQL) How to extract a json field with a dot inside (special character)

Tags: mysql, json

First of all, I am using **MySQL v5.7** .

Now, here is the problem...
This following example works (provided by Official MySQL website) :

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"id": 14, "name": "Aztalan"}', '$.name');
```

And it returns `"Aztalan"`.

But this one doesn't work:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"user.id": 14, "user.name": "Aztalan"}', '$.user.name');
```

How can I get the "user.name" json property name with json_extract function?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Working way is to quote the key:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"user.name": "Aztalan"}', '$."user.name"');
```

Comment: Fun fact, if you reverse the quotes so it's double on outside and single on inner, it errors

Comment: Also works with `?` such as 
select F_Settings->'$.\"opt_out_of_emails?\"'